# Angular JS script files loading sequence erroring?

Tags: angularjs, minify, angularjs-injector

I have a file "A.js" in which I have a initialised a module as given below

```
angular.module("x", []);
```

I have another file "B.js" in which also I have initialised a module as give below, in this case it is dependent on the "x" module as defined above in A.js

```
angular.module("y", ["x"]);
```

Now in the html file I have declared the script files as given below -

```
<script src = "B.js" ></script>
<script src = "A.js" ></script>
```

On loading the application, I am getting below error -

```
"Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] ..."
```

Question - Is the above error because the sequence in the HTML file should have been, first load A.js and then B.js since "y" module in B.js is dependent on "x" module in A.js?

Note - I have checked all the other probable places which could have caused the error, they are all fine. I am left with the above question only.

Comment: how do you instantiate your app?

Comment: yes, the order in which you have the script tags matters.

Comment: @Girafa - using ng-app in the html file

Comment: @Davin Tyron - So you are telling the error which is a DI error could be or is caused because of the above script tags?

Comment: you can try deferring application instantiation by manual bootstrap on dom ready for example.

Comment: One more thing i missed to tell, the above DI error am getting only after the files have been minified. Is that possible?

Comment: @Girafa - Please answer my above comment.

Comment: do you use explicit dependency annotation?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di did you read this? Espectially the part about dependency annotation?